# How can I optimize this SQL query with JOINS and nested SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

My SQL query takes a hell lot of time for execution because the transactions table is somehow very huge. I'm looking for ways to improve the performance of this query.

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.name as user, IFNULL(SUM(IF(transactions.recipient_account = users.account_id,transactions.money,0-transactions.money)),0) as total
FROM users as users
JOIN 
(SELECT account_id as system_account FROM accounts WHERE user_guid IS NULL AND name IS NULL LIMIT 1) as tmp
LEFT JOIN (transactions as transactions) 
   ON (users.account_id IN (transactions.sender_account,transactions.recipient_account))
WHERE (users.hidden = 0) 
   AND ((transactions.flags & 1) = 0 
   OR transactions.flags IS NULL)
GROUP BY users.user_guid 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 0,5
```

I've heart about indexes but I'm not sure how to utilize them here.

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: Pls provide us with the result of the explain and also provide us with the indexes you have on the affected tables and the fields those indexes include. Without these, any answer would be based on pure guesswork.

Comment: Very generally, you'll add indexes to columns that are used in the where clause of your queries.  You can add/drop indexes on those columns to see if it improves performance or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
accounts:  INDEX(user_guid, name, account_id)
users:  INDEX(hidden, account_id)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; with that, we might have further advice.

[*Index Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .